# What is the fastest way to download web pages'es sources?

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, task, httpwebrequest

I need to download numerous web pages' sources. So I need to do that as fast as possible. Here is my codes.

```
  private static async Task<string> downloadsource(string link)
  {                
     ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
     WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(link);
     req.Proxy = null;
     req.Method = "GET";
     WebResponse res = await siteyeBaglantiTalebi.GetResponseAsync();
     StreamReader read = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream());
     return read.ReadToEnd();           
  }

  List<string> links = new List<string>(){... including some web page links};

  private static List<string> source_list(List<string> links)
  {
      List<string> sources = new List<string>();

      for (int i = 0; i < links.Count; i++)
      {
          Task<string> _task = downloadsource(links[i]);
          Console.WriteLine("Downloaded : " + i);
          sources.Add(_task.Result);
      }            

          return sources;
  }
```

I was wondering if this code is the fastest way or it can be enhanced.
Can u pls help me with that ?

Comment: Even with multiple threads, the slow part of this process is always going to be the actual servicing of the request (i.e the network traffic). You may also find yourself meeting some nice 429 (Too Many Requests) errors if the webserver objects to a large number of requests in a short space of time

Comment: so u mean this usage is the fastest

Comment: I think he means that there are also other factors that affect how fast your algorithm will perform. Two of them are connection speed and host server settings.

Comment: I know but when we assume these factors are okey, only looking from the viewpoint of code ?

Comment: You are performing a `_task.Result` inside each loop. Your code will run as fast as if you downloaded each page one after another if you code it like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are performing a `_task.Result` call inside each loop. Your code will run as fast as if you downloaded each page one after another if you code it like that.

Try this instead:

```
private async static Task<List<string>> source_list(List<string> links)
{
    List<Task<string>> sources = new List<Task<string>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < links.Count; i++)
    {
        Task<string> _task = downloadsource(links[i]);
        Console.WriteLine("Downloading : " + i);
        sources.Add(_task);
    }

    return (await Task.WhenAll(sources)).ToList();
}
```

This would be even better:

```
private async static Task<string[]> source_list(List<string> links)
{
    return await Task.WhenAll(links.Select(l => downloadsource(l)));
}
```

Also I cleaned up your `downloadsource` method:

```
private static async Task<string> downloadsource(string link)
{
    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
    WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(link);
    req.Proxy = null;
    req.Method = "GET";
    using (WebResponse res = await req.GetResponseAsync())
    {
        using (StreamReader read = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            return read.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```